# Marginal Density of Product Distribution

Tags: probability, integration

RV of interest: $W=Vsin(\pi u)$; U and V independent.
$U\sim Unif(-1,1); f_v(v)=ve^{-v^2/2}$ on $[0,\infty)$.

$U* = \pi U$ also uniform s.t. $f_u^*(u*) = \frac{1}{2\pi}$ if u in $[-\pi,\pi]$, =0 o/w.

$f_x(x)=\frac{f_u^*(u*)}{\frac{dx}{du^*}}=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ if x in [-1,1], =0 o/w.

$f_w(w)=\int_x\frac{1}{x}f_x(x)f_V(w/x)dx$ (1)

or $f_w(w)=\int_v\frac{1}{v}f_v(v)f_x(w/v)dx$ (2)

For (1) and (2) I have the following integrands & stuck. Any help would save my day :)

(1): $\frac{w}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}e^{-w^2/2x^2}$dx

(2):$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-v^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{w}{v})^2}}dv$

Comment: Please [use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); images are unsearchable.

Comment: @J.G. is it still so??

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: @J.G. Just changed it! Thanks for letting me know.